# Rails 4; Reject params except raw JSON params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With Rails 4, I'd love to only accept JSON raw data as parameters.
There are some conditions below,

- Ignore parameters; `parameter` and `also`
  ( `http://example.com/page?parameter=value&also=another` )
- Fetch `page_id` ( `http://example.com/page/2/posts` )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring or accepting parameters is up to you inside your controller method.

It's difficult to offer up anymore advice without additional details of how you're receiving the request and what you plan on doing with it.

Getting the `page_id` depends on how you've got your routes set up. If you're using a resourceful route, then it should be available to you using params[:id].